# xsl for each number + 1

Tags: xslt, foreach

In a for-each Im using  to send 1,2,3,4 for each loop. I would like the count to start at 2 instead of 1. Is that possible?

```
<xsl:for-each select="BidFeeList/BidFee">
    <xsl:call-template name="chargeField">
        <xsl:with-param name="fieldIndex"><xsl:number/></xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:for-each>
```

So the for each would call chargeField template with 2 and then 3,4,5... etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have *n* `BidFeeList/BidFee` items and you want to call the `chargeField` template *n* times with the parameter `fieldIndex` set to 2, 3, ..., *n*+1. This can be achieved with the following XSLT fragment:

```
<xsl:for-each select="BidFeeList/BidFee">
    <xsl:call-template name="chargeField">
        <xsl:with-param name="fieldIndex" select="position() + 1"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Explanation: The XPath function `position()` returns the *context position* which in XSLT terminology is the one-based index of the *current node* in the *current node list*. In an `xsl:for-each` the *current node list* is set to the list of processed nodes and the *current node* is set to the currently processed node. Thus, `position()` itself yields 1, 2, ..., *n*. The `+ 1` takes care of counting from 2 to *n*+1 instead.